# Argumento inválido en open - Pyhton

Tags: python

¡Hola a todos! Estoy usando "open" en Python. El programa te pide el nombre y revisa si hay un archivo (.user) con ese nombre, de lo contrario procede a pedirte información como tu nombre, edad, etc. y con ello crea uno. Funciona bien si eres usuario nuevo, pero si ya tienes registro e ingresas nuevamente, al finalizar, no guarda tu nueva actividad, es decir, solo conservará la que hiciste cuando te registraste. Eso no debería suceder.

El IDE me indica lo siguiente:

```
archivo_usuario = open(nombre+".user","w")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Usuario/PycharmProjects/PracticaCoursera/MiRedS5-Archivos.py", line 99, in 
archivo_usuario = open(nombre+".user","w")

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Darwin\n.user'
.user

Es claro que el argumento es inválido porque hay demás esto: "\n", pero no sé dónde corregirlo ya que en la línea 99, que es la que me indica, no presenta ese problema.

Soy nuevo en esto, tal vez por eso no advierte el error. Gracias de antemano por su ayuda. Anexo un link a los archivos: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LmMkkEIKt2d6p_pBArLG0H67EFfTvLLo?usp=sharing

Comment: Aparentemente tu variable `nombre` contiene una cadena un poco extraña (`"'Darwin\n.user' "`, lo que incluye unas comillas, un retorno de carro en medio, la extensión .user, y un espacio al final). ¿De dónde obtienes la variable `nombre`? Esa es la línea que debes revisar, y no la 99 que es simplemente la que intenta abrir el fichero y se encuentra ya con ese valor incorrecto en la variable.

Comment: Te sugiero que pongas todo lo que haces con el ```open```, osea todo el procedimiento para guardar el archivo, para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Creo que el problema lo tienes en la línea 49, que es donde lees el nombre del usuario de un fichero. Las lecturas con `.readline()` incluyen al final de lo leído el `\n`. Este no te da problemas en otros sitios como la edad, o estatura, pues lo conviertes luego a `int` o `float`, lo que elimina el `\n`. Pero en los datos de tipo cadena como el nombre el `\n` queda. Para elminarlo puedes hacer `user = user.strip()`. Esta función elimina espacios (y retornos de carro) que pueda haber por delante y por detrás.

Comment: Gracias a todos. Me sirvió tu recomendación @abulafia